# How to store a string in a Solidity contract?

Tags: arrays, string, solidity, truffle

I am creating a contract that stores an array of strings.

I am testing the contract with truffle and ganache-cli. When I call the method `putData()` with any string, it gives the error `Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode`.

Here is the code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract DataContract {

    address public owner;
    uint public index = 0;
    string[] public data;

    // Constructor
    constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function putData(string _d) public {
        data[index] = _d;
        index = index + 1;
    }

}
```

How could I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're writing past the end of the array. (It's length 0, so there's no room to store anything.)

Just drop the `index` stuff altogether and use `push`, which will increase the size of the array for you:

```
function putData(string  _d) public {
    data.push(_d);
}
```